# Save Image Url in Cloud FireStore

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to create details of product in Cloud FireStore. Create document and save image in storage is all works. Mu issue is image url doesn't save in document.

dart file

```
  class ProductService {
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  void createProduct(_nameproductController, _priceproductController,
      _currentCategory, url) async {

    _firestore.collection("products").document().setData({
      'name': _nameproductController,
      'price': _priceproductController,
      'category': _currentCategory,
      'image': url,
    });
  }
}
```

upload image

```
void uploadImg() async {
var timekey = DateTime.now();
fb.StorageReference storageReference =
    fb.storage().ref('imgProduct/${timekey.toString()}.jpg');
fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTask = await storageReference
    .put(_image1, fb.UploadMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpg'))
    .future;

var imageUrl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();

url = imageUrl.toString();
print('Image Url' + url);}
```

submit button

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () async {
     if (_formKeyProduct.currentState.validate()) {
        uploadImg();
        ProductService().addProduct(
         _nameproductController.text,
         _priceproductController.text,
         _currentCategory.categoryname.toString(),
         url,
        );

        _formKeyProduct.currentState.reset();
        _nameproductController.clear();
        _priceproductController.clear();
     }

     setState(() {
        _currentCategory = null;
     });
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to await uploadImg();